# What do the rows of a matrix represent in relation to linear maps?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, linear-transformations

Let $K$ be a field, and let $\phi:K^n\to K^m$ be a linear map. Suppose $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix which represents $\phi$ with respect to the standard bases of $K^n$ and $K^m$. The $i$-th column of $A$ can be interpreted as a column vector which is equal to the value of $\phi(\mathbf e_i)$. Since $\{\mathbf e_1,\dots,\mathbf e_n\}$ is a basis of $K^n$, the value of $\phi$ at an arbitrary point $\mathbf v\in K^n$ can be determined just by knowing the values of $\phi(\mathbf e_1),\dots,\phi(\mathbf e_n)$.

My question is: is there a similar way of interpreting the *rows* of $A$? In particular, if we interpret the rows of $A$ as row vectors, what information do they give us about $\phi$?

Comment: Let $\{\epsilon_1,\dots, \epsilon_m\}$ be the dual of the standard basis in $K^m$ (i.e $\epsilon_i(y_1,\dots, y_m):=y_i$). Then, $\epsilon_i\circ \phi:K^n\to K$ is a linear map, whose matrix representation (a $1\times n$ matrix) is the $i^{th}$ row of $A$.

Comment: The rows could be seen as the vectors spanning the matrix's kernel...under the right interpretation (i.e., as coefficients of a homogeneous linear system)

Comment: In other words, the i-th coordinate of $\phi(v)$ is a linear function of $v$ whose coordinate expression is equal to the i-th row of $K$.